# Delete records from both SQL Server tables in a JOIN using a CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I want to delete records from both tables in the JOIN from the this CTE in `SQL Server 2012`:

```
WITH RECORDS_TO_DELETE ([Counter], [ID])
AS
(
SELECT D.[Counter], D.[ID], C.[ID] 
FROM [Table1] AS D
           LEFT JOIN 
               (
                 SELECT [ID] FROM [Table2]
                 WHERE NOT LOWER (COL1) = '*my criteria*'
                 AND (Date1 <= '31-Mar-2010' OR Date2 <= '31-Mar-2010')) AS C
            ON D.ID = C.ID   
)
DELETE FROM RECORDS_TO_DELETE
```

I have seen other examples that say its important to do this in the correct order but those examples are not in `CTEs`. I used a `CTE` because I have a convoluted `WHERE` clause (perhaps complicated by the fact my JOIN is to a result set) that I haven't felt necessary to include here. A `CTE` was the only thing that selected the data I wanted deleted.

Is there a way to delete records from both tables where there is a match between both tables?

Comment: You have to delete in 2 separate scripts for both tables, join `table1` with `cte` on id and delete records from `table1` and similarly for `table2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to delete the records from both tables, use your CTE to identify the primary key values for all of the records in both tables that you want to delete and write those values somewhere (table variable, temp table, actual table, probably based on the volume of your data).

Then execute two DELETE statements, one against each table, joining on the key values for the table in question.

You'll need that table to hold your values since, after you delete from the first table, your CTE won't work to identify the needed records anymore.

```
WITH cte AS
(
    INSERT YOUR LOGIC HERE
)
INSERT INTO @KeyValuesHoldingTable
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    cte;

DELETE Table1
FROM
    Table1 as t
JOIN
    @KeyValuesHoldingTable as h
        ON t.KeyValues = h.KeyValues;

DELETE Table2
FROM
    Table2 as t
JOIN
    @KeyValuesHoldingTable as h
        ON t.KeyValues = h.KeyValues;
```

Comment: Thanks Eric, I was hoping to avoid storing the unique values somewhere but guess it can't be done any other way. The database was designed before my time and wasn't designed to support the `cascading`.

Comment: @SSingh Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server only allows a `delete` statement to delete records from one table.

Two options come to mind for removing records from multiple.  The first is to define foreign key relationships with the `cascading delete` option.  The second is to define a trigger on a view that combines the two tables.

Neither of these are modifications really use a `delete` statement.  In other words, the database needs to be designed to support deletion from multiple tables at once.